# How can i make only the one i choose to hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, hide

Suppose i have 100 buttons, and i wanna make hide only 1, but i made the buttons with a for, is there a way to make that?

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#i").click(function(){
    $("#i").hide();
  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="1">Hide</button>
<button id="2">Hide</button>
<button id="3">Hide</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Update the query selector, write `$(\`#${i}\`)` instead. The one in your code evaluates to "#i" instead of "#1" "#2" etc.

Comment: Now only the third one hide, the others dont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    $(`#${i}`).click(function(){
      $(this).hide();
    });
```

Use the `for` loop inside the `$(document).ready` and use `this` instead of again querying the button

Comment: where can i do that? and any idea why this doesnt work? tableString += "<td><p><button id=" + ${seged} + "></button></p></td>";